# The Branch Cut of the Complex Logarithm Used by Default in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: complex, wolfram-alpha-queries

The title says it all: what branch cut (like which value of $k$ in $\ln(z)=\ln(r)+i(\theta+2\pi k))$ does Wolfram Alpha use by default in calculating the complex logarithm. I would say "principal branch"; however, [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2%20%2B%20%28i%2F%282*pi%29%29*ln%28-1*exp%28-i*2*pi*33%2F5%29%29%29*5%20) does not give me the same as [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2+%2B+i%2F%282+%CF%80%29+%28%28i*pi%29%2Bi+%28-%CF%8066%2F5%29%29%29%C3%975), even though I used the principal branch. It is entirely possible I made a mistake (in which so, some can tell me where), but even in that case, I still want to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

W|A uses the same branch as Mathematica: the [principal branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value).

We can see this by expanding the complex log, assuming both `x` and `y` are real:

```
ComplexExpand[Log[x + I y]]
```

> ```
> 1/2 Log[x^2 + y^2] + I Arg[x + I y]
> ```

Or by specifically asking:

```
FunctionRange[Log[z], z, w, Complexes]
```

> ```
> -π < Im[w] <= π
> ```

Comment: If so, why is there the difference in answers in the links?

Comment: It looks like you evaluated the log over a different cut. Yours evaluated to $-61 i \pi/5$, whereas the principal value is $-i \pi/5$.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you.